# Gatling foreach loop with doIf condition

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a chain of ChainBuilder objects to execute.

In one of them, I'm getting an *"id"*. Then I'm getting a list of tasks and trying to loop through them to find the one I need to complete.

But when I'm doing it like that, it says ***Type mismatch Expected: ChainBuilder Found: B***.

```
val processTask: ChainBuilder = getTasks
  .foreach("${tasks}", "task") {
    doIfEquals("${task.id}", "${id}") {
      exec(completeTask)
    }
  }

def getTasks: HttpRequestBuilder = {
  http("Get tasks")
    .get(tasksUrl)
    .check(jsonPath("$[*]").saveAs("tasks"))
  }
```

How to properly loop through the list with a condition?

Answer (score 2):

`.foreach` is a ChainBuilder method and you're trying to invoke it from a `HttpRequestBuilder` so it can't compile.

```scala
val processTask = exec(getTasks)
  .foreach("${tasks}", "task") {
    doIfEquals("${task.id}", "${id}") {
      exec(completeTask)
    }
  }
```